# Results of mixing HSbF6 and O2F2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, redox, halides, chemistry-in-fiction

I'm an amateur writer and one of the topics I deal with is what happens when a slightly-mad scientist and engineer is given an opportunity to work with full-on “magic.”  So there are situations where magic is analyzed and other situations where the technology that comes from that analysis seems on par with “sufficiently advanced technology”... and there are plenty of dangerous shenanigans that result; one of which is when an experiment on regenerative healing magic is contaminated with HeLa cells, accidentally creating a magically-fueled, self-sufficient cancerous growth.

One of the solutions I was looking at was Piranha Solution, but I got to wondering if that concept could be ramped up.

Thus, I was wondering if fluoroantimonic acid and dioxygen difluoride mixture would work in a similar, if more volatile and violent, manner, or if there would be other, undesirable reactions?

If it would work, what ratio would be the most effective?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioxygen_difluoride#Reactivity - If SbF5 alone would be used, maybe dioxygenylium salt might be obtained.

Comment: Mithoron:  I tried googling Dioxygenylium, didn’t really find anything on my level of understanding.  Could you or someone give me a quick crash course on what that is?

Comment: I'd recommend using artistic license. *Very potent*, potentially volatile, violent, virtually any desired property.